# Site loads on HTTP but not on HTTPS

Tags: html, ssl, cloudflare

Is there any reason why a file may load over http but not over https?
I am curious because I just enabled ssl on a subdomain and it does not seem to be properly. I can see the green lock but if i load the site with it, i see no files.

Like if I have a file at

```
http://site.exmpl.org/file.html
```

when i go to

```
https://site.exmpl.org/file.html
```

it does not load.

I have ssl enabled because i have the green lock, also i am using cloudflare if that helps

Comment: You don't have any antivirus software by any chance? If you do, turn it off and see if it loads.

Comment: For all dependencies using absolute paths, are you using either https or // for the file path? // as in <link href="//tomycssfile.com/styles.css" />

Comment: @ScriptsConnect - Good point, also check image paths, for example:

`<img src="https://www.example.com/myimage.png">`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you may have your SSL mode configured to "Full" in the CloudFlare Crypto section- But lack a ssl certificate installation on your subdomain.

--If not--

You may not have [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) or a Dedicated IP setup for your website then your apache server is likely using your certificate, but connecting to the web space of whoever first setup a SSL Certificate on that server. This is often a problem on shared web hosting environment. You can attempt to contact your provider to ask for help in getting SNI properly configured. You can also acquire a Dedicated IP from your provider.

Answer (score 0):

in cloudflare dashboard under SSL/TLS section go to Edge Certificate instead of overview.
In Edge Certificate there is option called "Always Use HTTPS" which explains "Redirect all requests with scheme “http” to “https”. This applies to all http requests to the zone." just turn in on and after sometimes you are good to go.